# How to not use session storage in security firewall with http_basic authentication?

Tags: symfony, security, session, firewall

I'm using Symfony version 2.7.29 and security firewall with http_basic authentication.

I don't use sessions at all but the security component write the security token on it. Is there a way to change this option? I don't like to have a locking resource used for no reason.

(In fact I use pages under authentication to perform some long task and having the session file open locks completely my navigation. If I disable cookies on the browser all works fine since create a new session every time, but this solution is not an option)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use null session handler for it. Change config to:

```
services:
    session.handler.null:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NullSessionHandler

framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.null
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work, but is there a way to say to the security component which storage to use for the security token? I think it would be a much elegant solution, plus, if I ever have to use sessions I would be able to.

Comment: I can't tell if it is possible